# heroku cant find file, works locally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

My app loads the files locally and everything works. But after deploying to heroku I get a 404(Not found). Any other file gets loaded and works fine, so I don't understand why these files are the only ones not loading.

My code actually:

```
(function(){
'use strict';
angular.module('app.core')
    .config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider.state('allArtikel',{
            url:'/allArtikel',
            templateUrl:'../app/artikel/html/allArtikel.html',
            controller:'allArtikelCtrl',
            parent:'/display'
        });
    });
})();

(function(){
'use strict';
angular.module('app.core')
    .controller('allArtikelCtrl',function($scope,$http){

    });

})();

<script src="app/artikel/js/allArtikel.controller.js"></script>
<script src="app/artikel/js/artikel.routing.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can use the `heroku <command>`. To get it clear, try to use `heroku bash` command, which will give you a bash line in your project on the server. Through it, you can review the files and find out what is where. (: